# kerberos apache 401 error for domain admins using office addin

Tags: domain, kerberos

I use SSO for access to a Linux based system from our windows 7 PC's.

This works for IE using the logon credentials to access the system.

However, when the developed office plugin is used by any member of the domain admin group it will not authenticate. The access_log has this in it:

- - [08/Sep/2014:11:57:48 +0100] "POST /cgi-perl/soap/soapservice HTTP/1.1" 401 4117 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.18063)"

However when I remove my self from the domain admin group and log back in, the plugin works all authenticated.

Any Idea's??